# How to void the extra "ht" in the docx converted by Pandoc

Tags: r, latex, docx, pandoc

I have a tex file like the following to be converted to docx by Pandoc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & PIK3CA & APC & ALDH2 \\ 
  \hline
Detection point & 120\~{}121 & 102\~{}104 & 76\~{}78 \\ 
  Genotype & -/- & A/A & G/G \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I use the Pandoc program (v1.11.1) to convert it, the docx content has this extra `[!h]` string, which should not exist as it's only a table placement parameter.

```
[!h]
    PIK3CA  APC ALDH2
Detection point 120~121 102~104 76~78
Genotype    -/- A/A G/G
```

And if I use `[ht]` as the placement parameter, I'd have an extra string of **[ht]** in converted docx.

Any suggestion to avoid it? Or is it just Pandoc couldn't handle it right the moment?

Comment: Perhaps there is a default setting in Pandoc for float specifiers. So, if you add `[!h]`, it technically boils down to you writing `\begin{table}[ht][!h]`.

Comment: @Werner OK, I think I got your point. You mean, without explicit specification Pandoc has its own `[ht]` or alike parameter. If we add `[!h]`, it becomes `[ht][!h]`, and if we add `[ht]` explicitly, it becomes `[ht][ht]` for Pandoc! So we should avoid any explicit specification for the table float here.

Comment: Yes. I'm just wondering whether there is a place where this default `[ht]` is specified, and perhaps remove it. Not sure whether that's what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, I think I found the mechanism behind it.

Per [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/pmiw78NvZl4/RMnCVKJr-k4J) about floating figures and tables by Pandoc at Google Groups and then Pandoc [release notes](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/releases.html)(search 'longtable' on the notes page), Pandoc currently use *longtable* for table formating and *longtable* actually doesn't do floating. This means no placement parameter is accepted by Pandoc, although by default the R package *xtable* generates the `[ht]` parameter.

So for anyone that uses *xtable* together with knitr and wants to convert the result to docx, you need hack the generated tex file by removing the placement parameter `[ht]`. (code adopted from [Yihui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17648350/2073130))

```
    x = readLines('foo.tex')
    # remove any placement parameters generated by xtable
    x = gsub('(\\\\begin\\{table\\}).+', '\\1', x)
    # write the processed tex file back
    writeLines(x, 'foo.tex')
```