# Are double "" and single '' quotes (always) interchangeable in R?

Tags: r, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

This is perhaps rather a minor question...

but just a moment ago I was looking through some code I had written and noticed that I tend to just use `="something"` and `='something_else'` completely interchangeably, often in the same function.

So my question is: Is there R code in which using one or other (single or double quotes) has different behaviour? Or are they totally synonymous?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I didn't know there was a `?Quotes` help page thx. my bad.

Comment: In the future, try `help.search("topic")`, using your preference of single or double quotes, of course.

Comment: do you mean `help.search(" ' ")` or `help.search(" " ")` ?

Comment: No, I meant `help.search("quote")` or `help.search('quote')`.

Comment: @StephenHenderson you mean `or help.search(" \" ")` LOL as in ["Single quotes need to be escaped by backslash in single-quoted strings, and double quotes in double-quoted strings."](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
> print(""hi"")
Error: unexpected symbol in "print(""hi"
> print("'hi'")
[1] "'hi'"
> print("hi")
[1] "hi"
```

Answer (score 30):

According to http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Quotes.html, "[s]ingle and double quotes delimit character constants. **They can be used interchangeably** but double quotes are preferred (and character constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are normally only used to delimit character constants containing double quotes."

Comment: thx I didn't know it had a help page. Thats quite clear though I think Jorans example is additional info too.

Comment: I disagree on the " preference. That requires the shift key, which slows typing and increases hand-strain. I always recommend '. If they are truly interchangeable, that breaks the tie for me.

Comment: @BryceChamberlain, you have a valid point. I sometimes switch to single quotes for that exact reason, but I end up switching back because habit is a bitch.

Comment: What about HTML popups in R?

Answer (score 19):

Just for curiosity, there is a further explaination in R-help mailing list for [*Why double quote is preferred in R*](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/228168.html):

> To avoid confusion for those who are accustomed to programming in the
>   C family of languages (C, C++, Java), where there is a difference in
>   the meaning of single quotes and double quotes.
>   A C programmer reads `'a'` as a single character and `"a"` as a character
>   string consisting of the letter `'a'` followed by a `null` character to
>   terminate the string.
>
> In R there is no character data type, there are
>   only character strings.  **For consistency with other languages it helps
>   if character strings are delimited by double quotes.**  *The single quote
>   version in R is for convenience.*
>
> (Since) On most keyboards you don't need to
>   use the shift key to type a single quote but you do need the shift for
>   a double quote.