# When do we use double quotes in R?

Tags: r

So,I am a very beginner in R,I wanted to ask this-
inside read.csv ,we are using "",but while writting summary/mean/sd etc. we don't use "". Why is this the case?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, when you make a question try to give: Input sample, expected output sample, what did you try and your research. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Hello Anuradha, I looked around a bit here on stackoverflow: This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572436/are-double-and-single-quotes-always-interchangeable-in-r) might help you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes `"` demark strings of characters, text inside code. Code itself is not double-quoted.

The following is valid code

```
name.of.file <- "C:\\Users\\bernhard\\valued_data.csv"
read.csv(name.of.file)
```

So you see, there is nothing special about `read.csv`, it takes the file name either as a string in `"`s or as a variable containing that string; no `"` in the latter case.