# different (wrong) behaviour of knitr hook with ggplot compared to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I try to create a bunch of graphics within a loop, and would like to add captions above by [using this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657216/caption-above-figure-using-knitr-latex-pdf).
Is it possible to modify this hook so it would be possible to submit a vector with length > 1 to `capT` and receive the same result as with `fig.cap` but with the caption above?
This document ends with an error!

The expected outcome would be:
First graphic with first caption, Second graphic with second caption etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

<<init, echo=FALSE, results='hide'>>=
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, 
                      results='hide', 
                      warning=FALSE, 
                      message=FALSE,
                      error = FALSE)

f <- function(x, options) {
  paste("\\end{kframe}\n", 
        "\\caption{", options$capT, "}\n",
        #"\\begin{figure}",
        hook_plot_tex(x, options), 
        #"\\end{figure}",
        "\n\\begin{kframe}", sep = "")
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = f)
@

Some Text.

<<first, capT=c('one', 'two', 'three')>>=
for(i in 1:3)
{
plot(1:10,1:10)
}
@

\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

This is working now. This was easy to fix. But now I have the problem with `ggplot2`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

<<init, echo=FALSE, results='hide'>>=
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, 
                      results='hide', 
                      warning=FALSE, 
                      message=FALSE,
                      error = FALSE)

f <- function(x, options) {
  paste("\\end{kframe}\n", 
        "\\begin{figure}",
        "\\caption{", options$capT, "}\n",
        hook_plot_tex(x, options), 
        "\\end{figure}",
        "\n\\begin{kframe}", sep = "")
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = f)
@

Some Text.

<<first, capT=c('one', 'two', 'three')>>=
for(i in 1:3)
  {
  plot(1:10, 1:10)  
  }
@

\end{document}
```

While using `plot()` leads to:

caption1 - plot1; 
caption2 - plot2; 
caption3 - plot3; 
(expected output)

`ggplot()` leads to:

caption1 - plot1; 
caption1 - plot2; 
caption1 - plot3; 
caption2 - plot1 etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

<<init, echo=FALSE, results='hide'>>=
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, 
                      results='hide', 
                      warning=FALSE, 
                      message=FALSE,
                      error = FALSE)

f <- function(x, options) {
  paste("\\end{kframe}\n", 
        "\\begin{figure}",
        "\\caption{", options$capT, "}\n",
        hook_plot_tex(x, options), 
        "\\end{figure}",
        "\n\\begin{kframe}", sep = "")
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = f)
@

Some Text.

<<first, capT=c('one', 'two', 'three')>>=
library(ggplot2)

for(i in 1:3)
  {
  d <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)
  p = ggplot(d, aes(a,b)) + geom_point()
  print(p)
  }
@

\end{document}
```

**Why is the output from ggplot2 behaving differently?**

Thank you!