# bookdown - how to get figure title above figure and figure notes below figure when using word_document2

Tags: r, ms-word, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to switch from LaTeX to RMarkdown+bookdown when writing a paper that includes tables and figures. One main motivation is to be able to create both Word documents and PDF documents.

For `word_document2`, how can I add a figure title/caption above the figure as well as figure notes below the same figure?

Here is how I would do it in LaTeX (and it would be convenient to continue using LaTeX as I am transferring everything over from LaTeX to RMarkdown).

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure Title...}
\label{figure_label}
\vspace*{.2cm}
\includegraphics[width=7in]{figure_name.png}\\
\caption*{Figure Notes...}
\end{figure}
```

More broadly, is it possible to use LaTeX code with word_document2?

Note that my preamble currently looks like:

```
---
title: "..."
author: "..."
date: "10/14/2021"
output:  
  bookdown::word_document2:
    number_sections: false
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    number_sections: false    
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{floatrow}
   - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}    
citation_package: default
bibliography: ../references.bib    
always_allow_html: true
---
```

And I am currently able to get the caption above the figure, but just for the `pdf_document2` (see [Caption above figure using knitr (LaTeX/PDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657216/caption-above-figure-using-knitr-latex-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

````
```{r figure-label, fig.cap="Figure Title", fig.width=6, fig.height=3.7, fig.align="center"}
...
````

This doesn't seem to work when creating the Word document.

Answer (score 3):

yihui says in his documentation¹ we can use the officedown² package to influence word layouts. It has the Plot- option topcaption: you can set it to true as shown below.

- [¹] https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-officedown.html
- [²] https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officedown/index.html

````
---
title: "..."
author: "..."
date: "10/14/2021"
output:  
  officedown::rdocx_document: 
    plots:
      style: Normal
      align: center
      topcaption: true
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    number_sections: false
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{floatrow}
   - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}    
citation_package: default
---




```{r figure-label, fig.cap="Top Caption", fig.width=6, fig.height=3.7}
plot(rnorm(1000,300,32))

library(officedown)

``
````

this should give you a docx with figure captions on top.

Comment: Thank you. This produces figure captions on top. Does it also produce figure notes on bottom (meaning the same figure has both a figure caption above it and figure notes below it)?