# Fig caption above figure in R Markdown PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, figure

I was wondering how I could get my captions to appear above my figures in R Markdown.

Here is a working example:

````
---
title: "Practical"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r fig1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:fig1}Caption"}
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
plot(x, y)
```
````

The question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657216/caption-above-figure-using-knitr), but the code suggested does not seem to work for me.

Comment: This will depend on the output format. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will compile and render in your intended format (e.g., pdf, html, docx).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335542/knitr-figure-captions-above?rq=1

Comment: After answering this question, I realised it was largely duplicated by the other post which was previously posted. I have modified my answer and reposted it there.

Answer (score 6):

When RMarkdown is run, it converts the base document to a LaTeX document using pandoc. As a result, we LaTeX packages can be used within the document, which can help in achieving advance customisation like this.

In this case, the [Floatrow package](https://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow?lang=en) can be used to reposition the caption above the figure. This is largely based of [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240004/caption-above-figure). It can be loaded by including `header-includes` argument within the YAML, as follows:

---

````
title: "Practical"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{floatrow}
   - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
---


```{r fig1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:fig1}Caption"}
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
plot(x, y)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I think putting `\usepackage{floatrow}` and `\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}` in the `preamble.tex` file of a bookdown template would be functionally equivalent, and possibly preferred if `header-includes` is passed to all output formats?

Comment: Yes, you could use either approach, as explained here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-preamble.html . If I have lots of code in my preamble, I tend to make a separate file of it. Not that when you say `passed to all output formats` specifying LaTeX packages will only work for PDF outputs, as Word and HTML do not use LaTeX when compiling. Hope that helps