# Can we keep the caption at the top of plotly objects in html output from rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-markdown, plotly

The following markdown shows the problem that captions that successfully go to the top of ggplot figures with the use of `fig.topcaption=TRUE`, but do not with **plotly** objects.

I learnt about fig.topcaption [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516108/4927395). The underlying code for the `fig.topcaption` appears to live here in [knitr](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/4dfd383aaea5975dd601b37d9fb44dada327e4b0/R/hooks-md.R#L57), though either that is not compatible with plotly figures, or it could be pandoc, or html/html widgets-related, or somewhere else in the chain from the rmarkdown to final output.

I'm happy enough with a work around for now - suggestions?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Internet"
date: "29 février 2020"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r setup, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

```

Here is a ggplot object with caption at the top as desired.


```{r, fig.cap="Hello ggplot", fig.topcaption=TRUE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
ggplot(diamonds,aes(price,carat)) + geom_point()
```

Here is the previous ggplot converted to a plotly object with caption reverting to the bottom.


```{r, fig.cap="Hello plotly", fig.topcaption=TRUE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
my_ggplot <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(price,carat)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(my_ggplot)
```

Caption reverts to bottom even if plotly object is not created from ggplot object

```{r, fig.cap="Hello plotly2", fig.topcaption=TRUE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
plot_ly(
  x=c(1,2,3),
  y=c(5,6,7),
  type='scatter',
  mode='lines')
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following [trick](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/figures.en.html) will work arround HTML output.
We can format the figure as a table (with image as it only cell) and the paragraph (where the figure caption live) as a table caption and place it on the top.

Just place this CSS chunk below YAML:

````
```{css plotly-caption, echo = FALSE}
div.figure {
  display: table;
}
div.figure p {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
}
```
````

Comment: Good solution for simple rmarkdown. In Bookdown, also works well for me - I used that css code and stuck it in my `style.css` file.