# Wrap text around an image in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a sample code below, and I would like to do the same [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551312/wrap-text-around-plots-in-markdown) for an image with better aesthetics.  Many thanks in advance

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "April 21, 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



## R Markdown
<div class="row" style="float:right;position: relative;padding-top: 30px;">
<img src="images/logo.jpg">

</div>



This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.


This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both contents as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Perhaps this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104599/float-graphic-figure-and-caption-around-text-in-rmarkdown-for-hmtl-output) might help.