# Quarto - unable to put captions above figure (docx format)

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I need to get Quarto to put figure captions *above* the figure, rather than the default (below).

Following the [documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#caption-locations) I used this:

````
---
title: "Test title"
format: docx
fig-cap-location: top
---

```{r}
#| label: fig-test
#| fig-cap: This caption should be above the figure
plot(cars)
'``
````

However, this renders like so:

[image]

I see that some people have resorted to [LaTeX customisations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657216/caption-above-figure-using-knitr-latex-pdf) or [knit hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335542/knitr-figure-captions-above), however I'm also failing at those (and I don't understand why the simple YAML marker I used, that is recommended in the documentation, isn't working).

**Edit**: as Mael pointed out, fig-cap-location is not an option for docx outputs. The Quarto documentation has since been amended to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the list of [MS Word options](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/docx.html), `fig-cap-location` is not actually one of them (compared to e.g., [PDF](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html) options), so this option is just not available with a docx output.

Comment: I see. So I guess my question is, how do I do this with a docx output?

Comment: It's going to be hard.  You **might** be able to do this by writing a Lua filter for pandoc https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html , but that's a pretty deep rabbit hole.  You could open a wishlist item at the [quarto issues list](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues) but, again, I wouldn't hold my breath ...  See https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2221