# How to hold figure position with figure caption in pdf output of knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using knitr (1.9.5 and 1.9.17) and rmarkdown (0.5.3.1), and would like to hold figure position in the pdf output. The generated pdf file is working fine when chunk option `fig.pos="H"` is used.

However, the figure position is not hold when `fig_caption: yes` is set in the 
yaml header.

How should I fix this problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

After learning the float environment of Latex. I add `float` package into header.

```
\usepackage{float}
```

But the generated tex file always use `htbp` in the `figure` environment regard to any `fig.pos` options are used. After manually changing `htbp` to `H`, positions of all figures are hold.

This is my example of rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
        in_header: mystyles.sty
---

# Section 1


Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.


```{r fig1, echo=FALSE, fig.height=8.5, fig.pos="H"}
plot(cars)
```

# Section 2

More test

```{r fig2, echo=FALSE, fig.height=8.5, fig.pos="H"}
plot(cars)
```

# Section 3

```{r fig3, echo=FALSE, fig.height=8.5, fig.pos="H"}
plot(cars)
```

More test
````

Comment: I found Yihui's answer here, which may answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc

Comment: I have had a similar issue. I am assuming that fig.pos is not actually parsed from .Rmd to Pandoc, because when examining the .tex output it just lists the 4 options [htpb] for your figure.

Comment: @kristang, As Yihui mentioned in his answer, we can not expect too much about formatting from markdown. Just write some R script to replace htpb to H. Will post my scripts.

Comment: Of course. I just found it weird it is listed as an option when it does not get parsed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Figure position in markdown when converting to PDF with knitr and pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc)

Comment: Literally none of these work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yihui mentioned in his answer ([Figure position in markdown when converting to PDF with knitr and pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc)), we cannot expect too much about formatting from mardown. To workaround this problem, just write some R scripts to replace `htbp` to `H`.

Compared with `knit` from knitr package, I found `render` from rmarkdown is better to export a `tex` file. Just remember to add `keep_tex: yes` in the yaml header of your rmarkdown file.

```
library(rmarkdown)
render('filepath.Rmd')
x <- readLines('filepath.tex')
pos <- grep('begin\\{figure\\}\\[htbp\\]', x)
x[pos] <- gsub('htbp', 'H', x[pos])
writeLines(x, 'filepath.tex')
tools::texi2pdf('filepath.tex', clean = TRUE)  # gives foo.pdf

file.remove('filepath.tex')
```

Answer (score 45):

For me adding the `float` package and then `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` in YAML solved the issue like :

```
---
title: "test"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document :
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
---
```

Comment: this solved the problem of `fig.cap` making plots take up an entire page for me

Answer (score 26):

As Andrew pointed out, this `fig.pos` doesn't work in chunks, but it does work if it is put in global options:

````
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H')
```
````

**EDIT:** the above apparently used to work and needs `\usepackage{float}` in the preamble:

```
header-includes:
 \usepackage{float}
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17648350/1548942) and the [Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html) for some other ways.

Comment: I found this to work except I had to use `fig.pos = 'h'` (i.e. lowercase instead of uppercase)... I also found that the location of this 'global_options' chunk matters, it has to be placed after the YAML header and before any chunks with include=TRUE.

Comment: Nice observation @InTheRed. Note that 'global_options' chunk name is arbitrary as far as I understand. The important part is that the `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` command - which sets the knitr chunk default options - should be executed as soon as possible during knitr-ing. So it should be somewhere at the top of the document.

Comment: This does not work for me and my figures are still floating around.

Comment: Sometimes this answer didn't work for me, but the answer above including `float` and `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` did work.

Answer (score 18):

**Update** look at this better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801326/1198125). (the summary of the problem below is still good, but follow the link to a better solution).

**To summarise some testing in RStudio**

The knitr chunk argument fig.pos = "H" works as long as `fig_caption: yes` is not in the yaml header.

Each figure in the generated .tex looks like this

```
\subsection{my_section}\label{my_section}

\includegraphics{path_to_fig.pdf}
```

But if `fig_caption: yes` is in the yaml header then the .tex looks like this

```
\subsection{my_section}\label{my_section}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{path_to_fig.pdf}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

`fig.pos = "H"` has not been used, `"htbp"` is there instead.

A workaround for this using RStudio:

put

```
fig_caption: yes
keep_tex: yes
```

in the yaml as well as

```
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
```

then search and replace `[htbp]` with `[H]` in the generated .tex file

then open the .tex file in RStudio and use the "Compile PDF" button.

---

**Example .Rmd**

````
---
title: "Testing fig placement with captions"
author: "Andrew Dolman"
date: "1 September 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.pos="H"}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.pos="H"}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: Miracle! Thank you so much!

Comment: This was a great help! Simply adding [htbp] after \begin{figure} did the trick - it held the figure in place.

Answer (score 11):

Although the answer provided by @Bangyou works, it complicates knitting.

You can also set a global default option for figure placement in latex, including this in your YAML header includes:

```
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\fps@figure}{H}\makeatother
```

As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364818/51645) (and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/51645) for the `\makeat...` part).

This way you can just use the knit button in RStudio or rmarkdown::render and be done with it.

Issue is, all figures fill be forced with H and you won't be able to set one to float around.

Comment: FWIW, of the solutions offered here, this is the one that seems to work for me.

Comment: This 1-line gem seems to me the definitive answer. Too bad so few upvotes!

Comment: This didn't work for me without the fig.pos = 'h' option also toggled on for each chunk, I've added a separate answer to summarize..

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Received error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \'H'.` Changed `H` to `h`. Did not need to add `fig.pos` to the code chunks. Everything works.

Answer (score 8):

The option that worked for me:

In the .tex put at the beginning: `\usepackage{float}`.

At the beginning of the Rmd: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H')`. The `H` in upper case).

And in every chunk with an image: `fig.cap="lorem blabla"` and `out.extra=''` (parameter value=empty string).

**No** need to define: 
`fig_caption: yes` and `keep_tex: yes` in the yaml.

These options make the image to keep their position, either for `include_graphics` and the plots generated by R code.

I used them in the `bookdown` enviroment, generating the pdf and the html as expected :)

Comment: This answer explains why the `out.extra` option is used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43245550/1494531

Answer (score 6):

The code from [Figure position in markdown when converting to PDF with knitr and pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc/33801326#33801326) helps me, help anyone else find it useful.

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "Martin"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options)  {
  knitr::hook_plot_tex(x, options)
})
```


```{r myplot, echo=FALSE, results='hide', fig.cap='Test', fig.pos='h'}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat)) + geom_point()
```
````