# Plots do not render properly in markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I have problem plotting side by side plots in markdown, instead, they are one after each other.

```
{r fn, fig.show = "hold", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,fig.width=5, fig.height=5, fig.path='figures/', dev=c('png', 'pdf')}
```

And this is the code to produce plots, sorry about the length. I have a few more plots in the document and all of them work the way I want them to work (using `par` or just markdown for stacking them together). I suspect it has something to do with the plotting code.

```
    list(structure(list(data = structure(list(model = c("90_10_12_rain", 
"90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", 
"90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", 
"90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", 
"90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", 
"90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain", "90_10_12_rain"), sens = c(0, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1), one_min_spec = c(0, 0.0412371134020618, 
0.0412371134020618, 0.0412371134020618, 0.0824742268041238, 0.0824742268041238, 
0.0824742268041238, 0.0824742268041238, 0.103092783505155, 0.103092783505155, 
0.123711340206186, 0.144329896907217, 0.164948453608247, 0.175257731958763, 
0.195876288659794, 0.237113402061856, 0.283505154639175, 0.319587628865979, 
0.373711340206186, 1), cut_point = c(NA, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 
14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
NA)), row.names = c(1L, 11834L, 11148L, 10462L, 9776L, 9090L, 
8404L, 7718L, 7032L, 6346L, 5660L, 4974L, 4288L, 3602L, 2916L, 
2230L, 1544L, 858L, 172L, 20L), class = "data.frame"), layers = list(
    <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
    x = ~one_min_spec, y = ~sens, label = ~cut_point), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = structure(list(line = structure(list(colour = "black", 
        size = 0.5, linetype = 1, lineend = "butt", arrow = FALSE, 
        inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", "element"
    )), rect = structure(list(fill = "white", colour = "black", 
        size = 0.5, linetype = 1, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
    "element")), text = structure(list(family = "", face = "plain", 
        colour = "black", size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
        angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.75, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 2.75, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.y = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 1, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        2.75, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.y.right = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 0, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 2.75), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
        colour = "grey30", size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
        hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
        margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.2, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 2.2, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.y = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = 1, vjust = NULL, 
        angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        2.2, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.y.right = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, 
        angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 2.2), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.ticks = structure(list(colour = "grey20", 
        size = NULL, linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, 
        inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", "element"
    )), axis.ticks.length = structure(2.75, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        axis.line = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), axis.line.x = NULL, axis.line.y = NULL, 
        legend.background = structure(list(fill = NULL, colour = NA, 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.margin = structure(c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
        5.5), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        legend.spacing = structure(11, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        legend.spacing.x = NULL, legend.spacing.y = NULL, legend.key = structure(list(
            fill = "white", colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.key.size = structure(1.2, class = "unit", valid.unit = 3L, unit = "lines"), 
        legend.key.height = NULL, legend.key.width = NULL, legend.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.text.align = NULL, legend.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.title.align = NULL, legend.position = "right", 
        legend.direction = NULL, legend.justification = "center", 
        legend.box = NULL, legend.box.margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 1L, unit = "cm"), 
        legend.box.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.box.spacing = structure(11, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        panel.background = structure(list(fill = "white", colour = NA, 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.border = structure(list(fill = NA, 
            colour = "grey20", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.spacing = structure(5.5, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        panel.spacing.x = NULL, panel.spacing.y = NULL, panel.grid = structure(list(
            colour = "grey92", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.minor = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.ontop = FALSE, plot.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = "white", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), plot.title = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 5.5, 0), class = c("margin", 
            "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.subtitle = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = 0, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 5.5, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
            debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(5.5, 0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", 
            "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag.position = "topleft", plot.margin = structure(c(5.5, 
        5.5, 5.5, 5.5), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        strip.background = structure(list(fill = "grey85", colour = "grey20", 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), strip.placement = "inside", strip.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = "grey10", size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4), class = c("margin", 
            "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.x = NULL, strip.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.switch.pad.grid = structure(2.75, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        strip.switch.pad.wrap = structure(2.75, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt")), class = c("theme", 
    "gg"), complete = TRUE, validate = TRUE), coordinates = <environment>, 
    facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, labels = list(
        title = "a) ROC for Tt = 10°C;RHt = 90%; \nSDt = 12 hours; and LW = rain and RH>90%.", 
        x = "one_min_spec", y = "sens", label = "cut_point", 
        intercept = "intercept", slope = "slope")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot")), structure(list(data = structure(list(model = c("88_10_10_rainrh", 
"88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", 
"88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", 
"88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", 
"88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", 
"88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh", "88_10_10_rainrh"), sens = c(0, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1), one_min_spec = c(0, 0.195876288659794, 
0.195876288659794, 0.195876288659794, 0.195876288659794, 0.206185567010309, 
0.22680412371134, 0.22680412371134, 0.247422680412371, 0.268041237113402, 
0.268041237113402, 0.306701030927835, 0.324742268041237, 0.358247422680412, 
0.394329896907217, 0.430412371134021, 0.551546391752577, 0.685567010309278, 
0.765463917525773, 1), cut_point = c(NA, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 
14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
NA)), row.names = c(1L, 12277L, 11591L, 10905L, 10219L, 9533L, 
8847L, 8161L, 7475L, 6789L, 6103L, 5417L, 4731L, 4045L, 3359L, 
2673L, 1987L, 1301L, 615L, 20L), class = "data.frame"), layers = list(
    <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
    x = ~one_min_spec, y = ~sens, label = ~cut_point), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = structure(list(line = structure(list(colour = "black", 
        size = 0.5, linetype = 1, lineend = "butt", arrow = FALSE, 
        inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", "element"
    )), rect = structure(list(fill = "white", colour = "black", 
        size = 0.5, linetype = 1, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
    "element")), text = structure(list(family = "", face = "plain", 
        colour = "black", size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
        angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.75, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 2.75, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.y = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 1, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        2.75, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.title.y.right = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 0, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 2.75), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
        colour = "grey30", size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
        hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
        margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.2, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
        vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 2.2, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.y = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = 1, vjust = NULL, 
        angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        2.2, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.text.y.right = structure(list(family = NULL, 
        face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, 
        angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 2.2), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), axis.ticks = structure(list(colour = "grey20", 
        size = NULL, linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, 
        inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", "element"
    )), axis.ticks.length = structure(2.75, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        axis.line = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), axis.line.x = NULL, axis.line.y = NULL, 
        legend.background = structure(list(fill = NULL, colour = NA, 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.margin = structure(c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
        5.5), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        legend.spacing = structure(11, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        legend.spacing.x = NULL, legend.spacing.y = NULL, legend.key = structure(list(
            fill = "white", colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.key.size = structure(1.2, class = "unit", valid.unit = 3L, unit = "lines"), 
        legend.key.height = NULL, legend.key.width = NULL, legend.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.text.align = NULL, legend.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.title.align = NULL, legend.position = "right", 
        legend.direction = NULL, legend.justification = "center", 
        legend.box = NULL, legend.box.margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 1L, unit = "cm"), 
        legend.box.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.box.spacing = structure(11, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        panel.background = structure(list(fill = "white", colour = NA, 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.border = structure(list(fill = NA, 
            colour = "grey20", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.spacing = structure(5.5, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        panel.spacing.x = NULL, panel.spacing.y = NULL, panel.grid = structure(list(
            colour = "grey92", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.minor = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.ontop = FALSE, plot.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = "white", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), plot.title = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 5.5, 0), class = c("margin", 
            "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.subtitle = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = 0, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 5.5, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
            debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(5.5, 0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", 
            "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag.position = "topleft", plot.margin = structure(c(5.5, 
        5.5, 5.5, 5.5), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        strip.background = structure(list(fill = "grey85", colour = "grey20", 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), strip.placement = "inside", strip.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = "grey10", size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4), class = c("margin", 
            "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.x = NULL, strip.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.switch.pad.grid = structure(2.75, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
        strip.switch.pad.wrap = structure(2.75, class = "unit", valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt")), class = c("theme", 
    "gg"), complete = TRUE, validate = TRUE), coordinates = <environment>, 
    facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, labels = list(
        title = "b) ROC for Tt = 10°C;RHt = 88%; \nSDt = 10 hours; and LW = rain and RH>90%.", 
        x = "one_min_spec", y = "sens", label = "cut_point", 
        intercept = "intercept", slope = "slope")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot")))
```

Comment: You are asking for plots to be 5 inches wide.  Is there enough room on your page for two of those?

Comment: Your code isn't usable:  things like `facet = <environment>` which you can see near the bottom are not executable.

Comment: Sorry, I thought dput will transfer everything needed for reproduction. I did not want to make any reproducible example because other plots in the same rmarkdown work, except for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use the code you posted. Would using the [plot_grid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cowplot/versions/0.9.3/topics/plot_grid) function from the [cowplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) be a potential solution?

You can easily generate figures with plots side by side using plot_grid. For example,

```
plot_grid(p1,p2,nrow=1,labels='auto')
```

Also, you may try editing your YAML header to include the following:

```
header-includes:             
- \usepackage{float}         
- \floatplacement{figure}{H}`
```

This will insure that figures are inserted where the code that calls them in the document. From **bthorne**, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486617/knitr-ignoring-fig-pos/43245550#43245550).

Comment: Thanks, useful answer, but not really what I wanted. There are a number of packages that do this, but I was hoping to figure out what happens in rmarkdown.