# When I knit to pdf my graphs and images do not appear in the order in which my code chunks are in the Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want my graphs, text and images to appear in a particular order as I am writing a data analysis project for university in R-Studio.

However, when I output to .pdf, the graphs, images and text appear jumpled up.

I was wondering if you would be able to help.

I have tried adding fig.show='hold' to the top of my code chunk.

Expected:

Heading1
Text1
Graph1
Image1

Heading2
Text2
Graph2
Image2

Heading3
Text3
Graph3
Image3

Actual:

Heading1
Text1
Graph3
Image1

Heading2
Text2
Graph2
Image2

etc.

In short, some graphs and images appear not in the same orders as the order I have constructed my document before knitting it to pdf.

Comment: Have you tried reordering the graph prints in your code to see how it would affect the outputs?  The compare and contrast will probably suggest the ordering solution.

Comment: Hi @SteveM, it seems that the order is dependent on the text I add. The more sentences I type changing the order of the graphs. It reminds me of text wrapping in Word.

Comment: I am not sure, but since pdf knitting goes through LaTeX, the latter takes care of putting the figures where it thinks it's best. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696172/how-to-hold-figure-position-with-figure-caption-in-pdf-output-of-knitr

Comment: Thanks @IsmailMüller, once I finished writing my document, there was only one graph out of place which I was was able to live with. Thanks everyone.