# Adding captions to figures/plots in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using rmarkdown to output a PDF document, however adding captions to plots seems not to be working. According to the docs, we're supposed to be using `fig.cap` to specify figure captions to pass to Latex. This is the header of my code chunk:

````
```{r Plot bond index returns, include = TRUE, fig.cap = "Bond index cumulative returns"}
````

I made sure to include the following lines in the header of the rmarkdown document

`output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: true`

This setup eliminates the entire chunk's output from the resulting PDF completely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you provide a little more detail? I can't reproduce this error. With a barebones .Rmd that looks like:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Test figure caption."}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I get an output like:

[image]

**Edit:**

After looking at the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696172/how-to-hold-figure-position-with-figure-caption-in-pdf-output-of-knitr), the following code generates figures with text interspersed with the figures:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
 \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'h')
```

Here is text number preceding figure 1

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Test figure caption."}
plot(pressure)
```

Here is text following figure 1

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Second test figure caption."}
plot(cars)
```

Here is some final text following the second figure
````

Comment: This seems to be working thank you, there is an issue with the positioning of the plots after I add captions, as they are all lumped together at the end of the document. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: @LorenzoNaletto - Glad that part worked- have a look at the edits for a possible fix, along with a link to the answer where I found that possible solution.