# How to stop a regression table and a graph from floating in a PDF Rmarkdown output?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, floating

I am trying to knit a PDF doc using Markdown and the regression table and one of the graphs are not in the place I wrote then in the rmarkdown file, which makes the report looking out of order. I have tried every solution I could find online but I would either get no results at all or error messages. I would appreciate help that would solve this issue.

I tried adding the following code to the end of every chunk.

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options)  {
  paste0(knitr::hook_plot_tex(x, options), "\n\\FloatBarrier\n")
})
```

I've tried the following at the top of chunks:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = "!H", out.extra = "")
```

I have also tried setting `fig.pos = 'h'` among many other codes with no success at all.

Comment: See if any of [these ideas](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html) help.

Answer (score 0):

For tables i use knitr::kable in combination with kableExtra::kablestyling:

```
kable_styling(latex_options =c("HOLD_position"))
```

For figures i used this: [How to hold figure position with figure caption in pdf output of knitr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696172/how-to-hold-figure-position-with-figure-caption-in-pdf-output-of-knitr)