# How to design PDF page in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, pagedown

When converting rmarkdown into PDF, is it possible to determine the position (on the page) and the size of the chart **very precisely** according to my needs?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696172/how-to-hold-figure-position-with-figure-caption-in-pdf-output-of-knitr

Comment: Not really, latex is notorious in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pagedown package you can position elements as you need.

When you put in a figure using an R code chunk, you can give it a caption like so:

````
```{r, example-label, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap="Example Chart"}

ggplot whatever
```
````

When you knit the document it'll then output your plot as a figure, which will be in a html img tag.
The caption from the code chunk will then be assigned as the **alt** property of the   img.

Then you can target the image using CSS.
For example:

```
img[alt="Example Chart"] {
  display: none;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply put in an image using markdown and then give it a style, like so:

```
![*An Example Image*](images/example.png){class="" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:50%;"}
```

In short, Pagedown can give you the ability to position and size charts as you want, if you're comfortable with CSS and/or HTML.