# Hold added image position in R markdown

Tags: r, image, markdown

I want to add an image in the middle of R markdown report, but when I knit it to pdf, the image appears on the top of the page, not in the intended place. Here is what I use in R markdown:

`![help_dataframe_screenshot](help_dataframe_screenshot.png)`

Anyone knows how to fix it? I need the image at where I insert it, not on the page top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rmarkdown Image Skips Ahead of Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145865/rmarkdown-image-skips-ahead-of-text)