# Fix external (not generated by R) image placement in Rmarkdown when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to generate a PDF from Rmarkdown that includes external images (i.e., not figures generated from R code, which has been addressed in other questions, but images from other sources). The problem is that when I generate the PDF, the images don't appear where I placed them in the source code, but rather are moved around, presumably so as not to break the text. To my knowledge, this does not happen with figures generated from R code - those are placed immediately after the R code that generated them.  Is there a way to fix this so that images are forced to appear in the text where I place them, as if they were generated from R code?

Some sample Rmd is below.  If either of the two images is large, one or the other will be moved until after the text.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "December 16, 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

## One image with text

If any of the images are too large, they will be moved elsewhere.

First image goes here:

![Image #1](pictures/image1.jpg)  

First image should be before here.

## Another image

Second image goes here:

![Image #2](pictures/image2.jpg)  

Second image should be before here.
```

Comment: I think this question has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc) and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17648350/3022126) before (from the author of `knitr` himself).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this question is dealing with images generated from R code and precise positioning of those images, whereas I just want the external images to appear where I placed them in the document.

Comment: @user3004015 I rolled back your edit. If you want to propose a solution to this problem, please post an answer to the linked duplicate

Comment: But my answer doesn't apply to the linked duplicate (which isn't really a duplicate; I tried to clarify this in my comments and edits to the question). I am talking about external images, whereas they are talking about placement of images generated by R. My answer wouldn't have any relevance for their question.