# How to force image to text when converting markdown to pdf using pandoc

Tags: pdf, pandoc, figures

I made a [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/LEEClab/LS_METRICS/wiki) - a manual to a software package - and I want to transform it into a beautiful pdf manual. However, I have some trouble with figures - many of them are put in one of the following pages, much after the place in the text where it should be, what turns the document very difficult to read.

To do so, I followed basically what was suggested [here](http://mountainbikesandtrombones.blogspot.com.br/2014/07/how-to-export-github-wiki-to-pdfs-andor.html). Basically the idea is to:

1. Clone the GitHub wiki;
2. Convert the markdown files to a single pdf using pandoc:

   pandoc -s FirstSection.md FirstSection.md FirstSection.md -o manual.pdf

What happens is that I have a sequence of short sentences, each one followed by a figure (take a look [here](https://github.com/LEEClab/LS_METRICS/wiki/Functional) for example). When I open the resulting pdf, each figure is not right after the sentence that precedes it in the wiki, but rather I have a sequence of many sentences and a sequence figures in a row, but it makes the document really hard to follow.

Is there a way of forcing the images to be right after a piece of text where they are placed, and avoid having the text that comes after it before the image?

I have found some solutions for Rmarkdown, but they did not work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pandoc uses LaTeX for [PDF creation by default](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf).

#### Using an external file

Put the [following](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/845#issuecomment-369944255) in e.g. `header.tex`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{h}
\makeatother
```

Or alternatively, the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc/33801326#33801326):

```
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
```

Then use:

```
pandoc input.md --include-in-header header.tex -o output.pdf
```

#### Using only a markdown file

Or instead of using a `header.tex`, you can also embed it in your markdown file's [YAML metadata block](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block):

```
---
header-includes: |
  \makeatletter
  \def\fps@figure{h}
  \makeatother
---

# my markdown header
```

Comment: Thanks, @mb21! It worked!
I found such a solution before for Rmarkdown, as in the link you cited, but as I am a beginner using pandoc from command line I could not figure out how to run pandoc using this .tex file...
thanks a lot!

Comment: The YAML metadata syntax might have changed a bit. According to the docs and what worked for me it would have to be 

```
---
header-includes:
- |
 ` ```{=latex}
  \makeatletter
  \def\fps@figure{h}
  \makeatother
````
  
---
```

Comment: The YAML metadata syntax might have changed a bit. According to the docs and what worked for me it would have to be 

---
header-includes:
- |
 ```{=latex}
  \makeatletter
  \def\fps@figure{h}
  \makeatother
\`\`\`  
---

Comment: @Jarno, that's simply using a [generic raw attribute](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute) inside the metadata field. Usually, it's not necessary. But if you have complicated LaTeX, it prevents pandoc from parsing it...

Comment: maybe the issue is then just that is should be `header-includes`, instead of `header-include`?

Comment: @Jarno, ah yes... typo... fixed!

Comment: I tried the YAML metadata block in my markdown file but it did not work. Part of the text in the document jump to before the figures.  (pandoc 2.5, with markdown generated from a Jupyter Notebook)

Comment: However using a .tex file with `\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure` in it worked. What is the meaning of the YAML header and what can we put in it to structure, format our document.