# nbconvert latex figure positioning

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pandoc, nbconvert

When I convert a notebook to latex (then PDF), the images are moved to the bottom of the page.  I figured that in latex, it would be possible to keep it in the current position using the 'h' placement specifier:

```
\begin{figure}[placement specifier]
... figure contents ...
\end{figure}
```

Is it possible to configure nbconvert to use that as a default value so I don't have to manually process is afterwards?

Reference: 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force image to text when converting markdown to pdf using pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040322/how-to-force-image-to-text-when-converting-markdown-to-pdf-using-pandoc)

Comment: Thanks, I have used the solution from the referenced article.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want by redefining the appropriate blocks in your template.

In [`document_contents.tplx`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/templates/latex/document_contents.tplx), note that blocks `data_png`, `data_jpg` etc all call the same macro `draw_figure`.

I did something similar to what you're after by redefining the figure blocks in my custom template to call a different macro `draw_figure_2` which I also defined in my custom template.

Adding something like

```
((*- block data_png -*))((( draw_figure_2(output.metadata.filenames['image/png']) )))((*- endblock -*))
((*- block data_jpg -*))((( draw_figure_2(output.metadata.filenames['image/jpeg']) )))((*- endblock -*))
((*- block data_svg -*))((( draw_figure_2(output.metadata.filenames['image/svg+xml']) )))((*- endblock -*))
((*- block data_pdf -*))((( draw_figure_2(output.metadata.filenames['application/pdf']) )))((*- endblock -*))


% copied macro draw_figure and made some naive changes; modify as needed
((* macro draw_figure_2(filename) -*))
((* set filename = filename | posix_path *))
((*- block figure scoped -*))
    \begin{figure}[h] % or whatever you want
    \begin{center}
    \adjustimage{max size={0.9\linewidth}{0.9\paperheight}}{((( filename )))}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    { \hspace*{\fill} \\}
((*- endblock figure -*))
((*- endmacro *))
```

Comment: Thank you - this looks very useful. However, after copying your code into my template file I get an error message:

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'output' is undefined`

when running

`jupyter nbconvert --to latex toplevel.ipynb --template latex-template.tplx`

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I tried to add `((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))` which stops the error but doesn't output the modified latex code either.

Comment: @ThorstenAltenkirch I'm not able to replicate the problem you are having. You might try replacing "data_priority" (see https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) just to check that the template is being used. Just add this line to your template: `((*- block data_priority -*)) data_priority was here ((*- endblock -*))` and you should see all your outputs replaced by the text "data_priority was here".