# Pandoc: how to keep order of images and subtitles when rendering md to pdf

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm working with a markdown document that imports images right after subtitles. This is my code:

```
## 2 - Characteristics of the respondents

### Gender of respondents
![Gender of respondents](../../../outputs/testing/Gender of respondents.png)

### Government tier
![Government tier of respondents](../../../outputs/testing/Government tier of respondents.png)

### Government sector
![Government sector of respondents](../../../outputs/testing/Government sector of respondents.png)

### Respondents in manager positions
![Manager position of respondents](../../../outputs/testing/Respondents in management positions.png)
```

Then I'm saving this into a file named `2-respondents.md` and I'm rendering it with pandoc using `pandoc 2-respondents.md -o example.pdf`.

The result looks like this:

[image: Page 1]
[image]

As you can see, my problem is that the third image is too long and the subtitles are rendered before the images.

Is there a way to make sure that the order of subtitles and images remains the same as in my markdown document? I found a similar issue [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000244/pandoc-md-to-pdf-keep-order-when-inserting-image-before-pagebreak), but it hasn't received an answer to date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my answer here:

[Pandoc Markdown to PDF image position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482221/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf-image-position#answers-header)

I needed to render using this command, which deactivates the `implicit_figures`:

```
pandoc 2-respondents.md -f markdown-implicit_figures -o example.pdf
```