# Image position in R Markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown, reporting

I want to insert an image in a R Markdown report, so i used this:

```
![Uniform Crossover](C:\Users\Miguel Prada\OneDrive\Documentos\Estudio\Invest UPM\ProjectANN\reports\crossover.png)
```

This works, but the image is located in the top of the page, not in the place where i wrote the code.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: are you rendering to html, pdf or word?

Comment: Hi Richard. I am knitting it to Pdf

Comment: Try `knitr::include_graphics` + use `fig.xxx` chunk option https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots

Comment: If you look up other discussions on how LaTeX deals with figure/picture/table placement, you'll see that it has its idea of what is best, defaulting to the top of the page following the paragraph to which it is "anchored". There are ways to override this, and perhaps `knitr`'s `fig.pos` can help, where you encourage LaTeX's optimization engine to bias in different directions. So, since you're producing PDFs, expand your learning to understand its use of `\begin{figure}[fig.pos]`.

Comment: Gentlement, thanks for your helpful answers. It worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2019, perhaps the best solution is to make a Latex preamble for your Rmd file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801326/1082004). In other words:

Save following preamble.tex file in your working directory:

```
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
```

Note that the ["H" tells the image to go where you insert it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text). Then call for the preamble.tex in the YAML header of your Rmd file:

```
---
title: "example"
author: "you"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output:
  rmarkdown::pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes        
    includes:  
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

![Uniform Crossover](C:\Users\Miguel Prada\OneDrive\Documentos\Estudio\Invest UPM\ProjectANN\reports\crossover.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Reply from comments

#### From [@tung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786542/tung)

Try `knitr::include_graphics` + use `fig.xxx` chunk option and see more in [options/#plots](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots)

#### From [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)

If you look up other discussions on how LaTeX deals with *figure/picture/table* placement, you'll see that it has its idea of what is best, defaulting to the top of the page following the paragraph to which it is "`anchored`".

There are ways to override this, and perhaps `knitr`'s can help, where you encourage LaTeX's optimization engine to bias in different directions. So, since you're producing PDFs, expand your learning to understand its use of `\begin{figure}[fig.pos]`.