# Problem with graphics grouping together in R Markdown with knitr (excludes text between)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, visualization

Despite having text separating my graphics in RMarkdown (using knitr), how can I prevent my graphics from grouping together?

I've posted two screenshots, one of the PDF output and one of the code. Note that there is a line of text between the two graphics in my markdown file but that line is stripped away in the output.

[image: Code View]

[image: PDF Output View]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please ask a standalone question with no external links. Images can be [integrated to the site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: You need to show us how you inserted the graphics.  This page:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801326/2554330 shows one way to do what you want, but I don't know if it will apply to your code.