# Boxplot Moving Right Off PDF Page

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, boxplot

Using RStudio 2023.06.1 Build 524, R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01), x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Linux Mint.

```
arr = rnorm(1000, 50, 20)
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
boxplot(arr, ylim=c(0,70), col = "red")
boxplot(arr,ylim=c(0,70), col = "#EEEEEC")
boxplot(arr,ylim=c(0,70), col = "blue")
```

The output is moved to the right, where one of the plots is off the pdf.
Like so:
[image]

***Suggestions?***

Comment: How are you generating a PDF? Your code doesnt show this. Does it show up in your Rstudio "plots" viewer? Is this in markdown?  Also, I assume you mean `arr = rnorm(1000, 50, 20)`? Providing a little more information about how you are encountering this problem will help you get better, faster help.

Comment: Yes, generating PDF, I am using Knitr to generate. Sure, but I'm not sure what else to add...

Comment: I can't replicate the issue using standard r-markdown pdf output https://i.imgur.com/pBnUKkG.png

Comment: Have you tried solution from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eva for bringing this post to my attention:
[figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc)

The last answer gave me something that worked, (although I did modify it slightly).

ADD to Yaml

```
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "title2"
author: "By na"
pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_crop: no
    fig_height: 2
    fig_width: 3
    keep_tex: no
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
---
```

THEN by adding this to the first code chunk

```
{r LoadData, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
# DO NOT SHOW IN FINAL REPORT
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
options(digits = 5) 

#Load Libraries
Libraries <- c("knitr", "readr")
for (p in Libraries) { 
    library(p, character.only = TRUE)
}

opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center',
               external=TRUE,
               echo=TRUE,
               warning=FALSE,
               fig.pos='H'
               )
```